# C strings/char arrays

Tags: c

I hope I can get this figured out. I am attempting to write a program that acts the same way as the sed command. My issue is within the **isMatch** function I have written. Something is either not right or is missing. The way the code works is the user executes the program as **./sed aaa bb** the second arg **aaa** is used as the string to find in the user entered string and the third arg **bb** is its replacement. As it works now the program just echos the user input without any changes. How I am attempting for it to work is by building a new string with the proper output.

For example user enters **./sed aaa bb** "Enter" then is prompted to enter a string like **aaaabc** where the string printed out is **bbabc**

The isMatch function is supposed to compare the elements in inputString one by one to the oldString and return 0/1 which tells the main method to print the inputString character as is or to print the substitution instead.

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isMatch(char * oldS, char * inS){
    int i;                                                                                                                  
    for(i=0;i<strlen(inS);i++){
            if(inS == &oldS[i])
                    return 0;
            else
                    return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  }
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {                                                                                             
         int i;                                                                                                                  
         int match;                                                                                                              
         char c;                                                                                                                 
         char input[100];
                                                                                                                            
         while(1){
            printf("Enter the string to be changed: ");

            if(scanf("%c",&c) == EOF){
                    break;
            }

            if( (input[0] = c) != '\n'){
                    for(i=1;i<100;i++){
                    scanf("%c",&input[i]);
                            if(input[i] == '\n' ){
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }

            for(i=0;i<100;i++){
                    match = isMatch(argv[1],&input[i]);
                    if(match != 0){
                            printf("%c",input[i]);
                            if(input[i] == '\n' ){
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
                    if(match = 0){
                            printf("%s",argv[2]);
                    }
            }

    }
 }
```

Comment: There are several issues with the code: In `isMatch`, you are doing pointer comparison, which always be false, as ``oldS` and `inS` will point to different memory locations. Also, the loop in `isMatch` will always only do one iteration, because both the `if` and the `else` case do a `return`. Also, there is a `return` missing at the end of the function (you should compile with maximum compiler warnings enabled to catch this kind of problem). In your `main` function, there is a `if(match = 0)`, which does assignment instead of comparison, use `==` instead.

Comment: Even with these issues resolved, it's not clear to me how the code is supposed to solve the problem. I don't think it can be fixed by changing one or two lines. But also I don't think it would be helpful to you if someone would just answer with a complete rewrite of your code. I think it would be more productive if you could add some comments to your code, describing for each part what you intend it to do. That would make it easier to explain where your intention deviates from what the code does.